# Is there a relation between isometric and orthographic measurements?

Tags: geometry, visualization

[This](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/3D_shapes_in_isometric_projection.svg) image shows a couple of different isometric projections. In the black shows the figure's "true" dimensions in an orthographic projection while the red shows the dimensions in an isometric projection.

Is there a relation between the two numbers?

Comment: What kind of relation do you mean? A global formula?

Comment: Yeah, a formula where I input either of the two numbers and get the other one, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not such a function you want. Functions are well defined but for different inputs we may have several outputs. For example in cylinder two segment with length 1 have different vision lengths 1 and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

We should know three parameters which describes 3D shape then we can calculate vision length with Pythagorean Theorem.